# Is there any Dapper like micro ORM for Python?

Tags: python, mysql, orm, micro-orm

I know there are multiple ORMs for python, but I like the idea of Dapper - a simple object mapper. 
I googled but can't find any Dapper like ORM for python. 
Is there any existing dapper like micro-ORM for python ?

Answer (score 9):

I’m the author of pydapper https://pydapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. It’s a pure python lib inspired by dapper!

Comment: Nice, truly like dapper. Unlike other suggested micro orms

Comment: I have an existing DB and want to try pydapper, but how to change map classes' fields to table columns (example: class have ID field but it maps to ID_Proprietario)?
How I do that (which I already solved in dapper.net)?

Comment: looks neat but it's a bit unclear if and how it supports other drivers than the ones covered in the docs

Answer (score 7):

There is [PonyORM](https://ponyorm.org/) that is a simple lightweight ORM that is similar to Dapper but oriented towards Python.

Other options are [PeeWee ORM](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) or the granddaddy [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

Comment: SQLAlchemy does Micro ORM? I couldn't find Micro ORM document on SQLAlchemy website.

Comment: SQL Alchemy includes an ORM. It is more of a toolkit for databases. If you want "micro" Pony is probably your best option